# What exactly size of image should I prepare for my Android application's background?

Tags: android

When the application runs, it will stay at a banner page for 3 seconds.
So my question is what size of that banner should I prepare and
is it one set of image is fine?

Comment: unless you have a really good reason for it (like an actual long loading time), you should not display a splash screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your targeting resolution. To get better result you should use multiple images for different dpi and resolution. follow this guideline: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html